# Why when I run my script, the downloaded image files have zero bytes and I receive attribute error?

Tags: python-3.x, reddit

I am still new to python and trying to practice by building a few scripts. This one should find the hot submissions in an image subreddit and download those images to the redditpics dir path using the basename of the submission url. I'm using python 3.7. 
First I tried just this:

```
import praw, requests, os, bs4

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxx', 
                      client_secret='xxxx',
                      user_agent='picture downloader',
                      username='xxxx',
                      password='xxxx'
                      ) 
print(reddit.read_only)

os.makedirs('redditpics', exist_ok=True) 
for submission in reddit.subreddit('earthporn').hot(limit=50):
    url = submission.url
    print(url)
    imageFile = open(os.path.join('redditpics', os.path.basename(url)), 'wb')
print('Done')
```

The downloaded images have zero bytes of information. Then I added the following from automate the boring stuff:

```
imageFile = open(os.path.join('redditpics', os.path.basename(url)), 'wb')
for chunk in url.iter_content(100000):
    print("saving " + imageFile)

    imageFile.write(chunk)
imageFile.close()
print('Done.')
```

But I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter_content'`

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error using automate the boring stuff and online searching, this ended up working:

```
for submission in reddit.subreddit('earthporn').hot(limit=50):
print(submission.url)
url = requests.get(submission.url)
imageFile = open(os.path.join('redditpics', os.path.basename(submission.url)), 'wb')
for chunk in url.iter_content(100000):
    print("saving " + str(imageFile))

    imageFile.write(chunk)
imageFile.close()
```